# How to switch to qemu monitor console when running with "-curses"

Tags: qemu

When passing "-curses" option to qemu, qemu displays the emulation window as default. So, how can I switch to the monitor console from the emulation window? If using graphical interface, switching between emulation window and monitor console can be achieved by "ctrl+alt+(1 or 2)". I am just not sure how to do this in the non-graphical case.

Answer (score 32):

Just use Esc instead of Ctrl-Alt. So to switch to the monitor console use Esc+2. To switch back to the terminal output use Esc+1. You can similarly switch ptys with Esc+F2 etc.

Comment: Hi, the ESC+1 and ESC+2 worked great for me for years. But now that I upgraded my system and I'm using QEMU 4.2.0, those shortcuts for switching to the monitor and back don't work anymore. Any ideas? Note: Alt+1, Alt+2 still work, but I need to use ESC+1, ESC+2 to avoid conflicts with the other shortcuts of the terminal emulator. How can I re-enable ESC+1, ESC+2 ?

Answer (score 30):

From the section [keys in the character backend multiplexer](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/mux-chardev.html) in the QEMU docs:

> During emulation, if you are using a character backend multiplexer (which is the default if you are using -nographic) then several commands are available via an escape sequence. These key sequences all start with an escape character, which is Ctrl-a by default, but can be changed with -echr. The list below assumes you’re using the default.
>
> …
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>
>
> Rotate between the frontends connected to the multiplexer (usually this switches between the monitor and the console)

Comment: Beware that if you also use `-monitor` without `-serial mon:stdio`, QEMU disables this escape sequence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716931/how-to-run-qemu-with-nographic-and-monitor-but-still-be-able-to-send-ctrlc-to/49751144#49751144

Comment: Linked documentation is unfortunately dead, wayback machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20131223164110/http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#Keys

Use `Ctrl+a`, `c` again to toggle back.

Answer (score 15):

Doesn't appear to be possible. However, you can access the monitor console via Telnet.

Start QEMU:

```
qemu-system-i386 -curses -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1234,server,nowait
```

Then, to access the monitor console, type this in another terminal:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 1234
```

Comment: `ctrl + a c` reported by nikitis seems to be better (you can see the boot process).

Comment: You likely also want `-serial mon:stdio`, otherwise Ctrl+C does not get passed to guest anymore due to `-monitor`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716931/how-to-run-qemu-with-nographic-and-monitor-but-still-be-able-to-send-ctrlc-to/49751144#49751144

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

Just drop the 'ctrl' and all of the key sequences work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me. I have Ubuntu 16.04, I don't think this matters.

`Ctrl + Alt + 2` worked for me.

Comment: This likely changes the TTY on the host, not the guest.