# How to run qemu with -nographic and -monitor but still be able to send Ctrl+C to the guest and quit with Ctrl+A X?

Tags: qemu

I have just found out that if you run QEMU with `-monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -nographic`, then Ctrl-C kills the QEMU VM instead of generating SIGINT on the guest: [How to pass Ctrl-C to the guest when running qemu with -nographic? | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167165/how-to-pass-ctrl-c-to-the-guest-when-running-qemu-with-nographic/436321#436321)

However, I don't want to remove `-monitor` because it is convenient to automate monitor commands, e.g. it allows me to create a helper script that does:

```
echo 'savevm my_snap_id' |  telnet localhost 45454
```

Is there a way to both keep my `Ctrl-C` and `-monitor` working with `-nographic`?

Full QEMU command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -append 'root=/dev/vda console=ttyS0' -kernel 'bzImage' -drive file='rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2' -nographic -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait
```

On QEMU 2.10.1, Ubuntu 17.10, full QEMU command:

```
./x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0 nokaslr printk.time=y" \
-drive file="${dir}/out/x86_64/buildroot/images/rootfs.ext2.qcow2,format=qcow2" \
-kernel "${dir}/out/x86_64/buildroot/images/bzImage" \
-nographic \
```

If I add:

```
-chardev stdio,id=s1,signal=off \
-serial none -device isa-serial,chardev=s1
```

then `Ctrl+C` starts working as desired, but `Ctrl+A X` does not work to quit QEMU, which is annoying sometimes: I can use `telnet` to `quit`, but it requires more typing / automation.

http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2018-04/msg00006.html

Comment: You need to send those keys to the alternative monitor device somehow.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev what is the alternative monitor device, how do I use it?

Comment: https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev sorry, I can't find "alternative monitor" there

Comment: The `-monitor` option has a default, described in the doc. By "alternative device", I meant the device that you instruct `qemu` to use instead of the default.

Answer (score 15):

**Add `-serial mon:stdio` and remove other `-serial` options**

The following satisfies all my requirements:

```
./x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -append 'root=/dev/vda nopat nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y console=ttyS0' \
  -drive file="${dir}/out/x86_64/buildroot/images/rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2" \
  -kernel "${dir}/out/x86_64/buildroot/images/bzImage" \
  -nographic \
  -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait \
  -serial mon:stdio
```

Or for aarch64:

```
./aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M virt \
  -append 'root=/dev/vda nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y' \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -drive file="${dir}/out/aarch64/buildroot/images/rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2" \
  -kernel "${dir}/out/aarch64/buildroot/images/Image" \
  -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait \
  -nographic \
  -serial mon:stdio \
```

Tested on QEMU 9d2a09063922757ec3640d93f6b35921ab95b1c2
 (post v2.12.0-rc2).